# Spark: Saving pair RDD as append mode in same output folder

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing my spark output as below

```
pairedRDD.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(noOfHashPartitioner)).saveAsHadoopFile(output, classOf[String], classOf[String], classOf[RddMultiTextOutputFormat], classOf[GzipCodec])
```

But in this case every time i need to delete the output folder and then run my spark job ,instead i want to write my output in the same output folder again and again on S3 .

The reason for this is output of my spark code is millions of small xml files and to run my spark code i need to copy output to another S3 folder that takes lots of time because of the huge size and small number of objects .

So we wanted to have something in spark so it can write in the same folder or keep appending output in the same folder .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this .

```
conf.set("spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs", "false")
```